# Cannot downgrade Android minimum sdk

Tags: android, sdk, gradle

I have just created my first android app (for the um-teenth time).  I created the project with a higher sdk than I intended, and now I want to lower it.  My initial android maifest did not contain a `<uses-sdk>`section, so I added:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="17"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17"
    android:maxSdkVersion="21" />
```

I also updated my build.gradle file to (relevant section):

```
 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "dkuehn.myapp.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 17
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
 }
```

However, after syncrhonizing my app, and attempting to run, my AVD screen looks like this: 
[image]

So neither my s5 plugged via USB running what I believe is 4.2.2 and the emulator that is minimum SDK (assuming 21 is in fact above 20 L) are compatabile.  But I still want to lower the minimum sdk so I can use my phone and not rely on emulators for now.

The AndroidManifest in the /build/ folder looks like this:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:maxSdkVersion="21"
    android:minSdkVersion="L"
    android:targetSdkVersion="L" />
```

Update: my compile options within build.gradle
My dependency options for build.gradle are:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.2.42'
    //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+'
}
```

Comment: All packages are updated in SDK Manager?

Comment: Try removing the uses-sdk from your manifest file.

Comment: @AlexL. what packages do I have to have installed?  Every package between my minimum and the target?

Comment: @dckuehn no, fortunately! But there may have frequent update from Google (bug fixing, etc) so it's just a minor question.

Comment: I looked at it after you asked and realized I had only installed 21, and 20.  Installed 17 just now, and in progress of installin gall between 5.0 and 4.2.2 just for funzies.  When that's done, I'll try @Gero 's suggestion.

Comment: @Gero no luck, and updated SDK Manager doesn't show any difference either.

Comment: Sorry but the last thing i came up is to make a "clean" going to Build->Clean project, or deleting the "build" folder.

Comment: clean/rebuild showed no changes.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the Developer Preview versions of some dependencies, which enforce a strict 'L' min and target SDK.

Look for dependencies such as

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0-rc1'
```

And replace them with the now released Android Lollipop versions (which allow them to be used from their min SDK to API21 devices):

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
```

Comment: In my initial build, I had some jar's throwing some errors.  I commmented out the jars in my dependencies within build.gradle.  Is this what you mean?  See my edit, @ianhanniballake